# QGIS 2.6 Crashed for my own plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, python-2.7, qgis-2.6

I had developed a plugin that counts the number of features for a layer in QGIS 2.6. I am using Windows 7 os. It works fine when i loaded a layer. But when I remove that added layer and then if I click the plugin it gets crashed. The snapshot is attached.

[image: error dialog]

The part of the dump file error is also attached:

[image].

Here is function which does the main work of the plugin.

```
def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()
    for layer in layers:
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
            self.dlg.featurecombo.addItem( layer.name(), layer )
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result  == 1:
        index = self.dlg.featurecombo.currentIndex()
        layer = self.dlg.featurecombo.itemData(index)
        if layer > 0:
            QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(),"feature count","%s has %d features." %(layer.name(),layer.featureCount()))
        else:
            QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(),"Warning!",'Touch me after loading a layer!')
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.
            pass
```

Comment: It might be useful to have a look at the contents of the .DMP file. You can open those in any text editor. Usually they will give you some pointers on what is causing the conflict. You could post a shot of the file with your question, that might help others work out what is going on. IMHO... Just don't click the plugin when you don't have a layer loaded!

Comment: A link to the code will help.

Comment: The function which does the main job of the plugin is attached above for reference.

Comment: I tried clearing the combo box before loading the layer and now it works fine without any dumpfile creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says something about duplicate names. It seems that you must clear the QComboBox you are using, before loading the layers again.

You can clear a `QComboBox` by calling its `clear()` method. In your case, it would make sense to edit the `run()` method, so that every time the user launches the plugin (for example, by clicking the plugin's main button), the `QComboBox` is cleared before layers are added to it:

```
def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()

    # Clear the QComboBox before loading layers
    self.dlg.featurecombo.clear()    

    layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()
    for layer in layers:
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
            self.dlg.featurecombo.addItem( layer.name(), layer )
```